# How payflow handle proration in upgrading subscription plans?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, payflowpro

I have scenario in pay flow recurring payment.
suppose if a user subscribe for "Quick Start ($40)" then upgrade its subscription to "Advance Plan($80)", how much payflow will charge user on next billing cycle, $40 (Price difference) or $80 (Advance Plan Price). What if i want  user to pay only price difference. Please help. i could not find any solution after day of googling.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Paypal does not support automatic proration payment (while stripe does). If you need to stick with Paypal, calculate the proration by yourself and request the user to pay it separately. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/subscriptions/customize/revise-subscriptions/